# Are class data members initialized before the copy constructor when using the copy constructor?

Tags: c++, class, pointers, memory-leaks, copy-constructor

For example, if I have this class:

```
class Counter {
public:
    int* j = new int[5];
}
```

A pointer variable is initialized as a data member. If in my copy constructor, I have something like

`int* j = new int[7]` OR `int* j = new int[5]()`,

therefore initializing the the data member as well, will it create a memory leak for the first one since it wasn't deleted beforehand? Or will the original data member not even initialize?

Comment: There's nothing special about a copy constructor in this regard. How about you try a mental experiment: in your default or explicit constructor, if you do the same thing, do you think you'll leak memory?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I think unless initialized in the constructor initializer list, yes it would also create a memory leak.

Comment: There you go, you figured this out yourself!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### A default member initializer for a non-static data member will be used in constructors where the same data member is not present in the member initializers list

> [...] will it create a memory leak ... ?

Yes.

A *default member initializer* (DMI) as used in your example:

> ```
> class Counter {
> public:
>     int* j = new int[5];  // default member initializer for data member 'j'
> }
> ```

will *only be used* if, for a given constructor, the data member, here `j`, is not initialized in the *member initializer list* of that given constructor.

Thus, if you add a copy constructor to `Counter` with *no member initializer list*, the default member initializer for the data member `j` will be used, and thus you will have a memory leak.

We can study this behaviour by changing the DMI for the data member `j` into an immediately invoked lambda, to allow us to trace when the DMI is used or not, as well as a dummy copy ctor that simply copies the pointer of the copy-in argument through different means (this is just for this dummy example; see final paragraph regarding lifetime management as well as deep-copying vs shallow-copying):

```
#include <iostream>

struct Counter {
    int* j = []() { 
        std::cout << "Calling DMI for j.\n";
        auto p = new int[5];
        return p; }();

    // Uses the DMI for member 'j'.
    Counter() {}

    // Uses the DMI for member 'j'.
    Counter(const Counter& c) { j = c.j; }  // Memory leak.
};

int main() {
    Counter c1;       // Calling DMI for j.
    Counter c2 = c1;  // Calling DMI for j.

    // Delete resource common for c1 and c2.
    delete c2.p;      // A rogue resource from c2 construction was leaked.
}
```

If your either perform the copying *into* the `j` data member in a member initializer list of the copy constructor:

```
#include <iostream>

class Counter {
public:
    int* j = []() { 
        std::cout << "Calling DMI for j.\n";
        auto p = new int[5];
        return p; }();

    // Uses the DMI for member 'j'.
    Counter() {}

    // Does not use the DMI for data member 'j'.
    Counter(const Counter& c) : j(c.j) { }
};

int main() {
    Counter c1;       // Calling DMI for j.
    Counter c2 = c1;

    // Delete resource common for c1 and c2.
    delete c2.p;  // OK, no resources leaked.
}
```

or simply explicitly set the data member `j` to `nullptr` as part of a member initializer list in the copy ctor:

```
#include <iostream>

class Counter {
public:
    int* j = []() { 
        std::cout << "Calling DMI for j.\n";
        auto p = new int[5];
        return p; }();

    // Uses the DMI for member 'j'.
    Counter() {}

    // Does not use the DMI for data member 'j'.
    Counter(const Counter& c) : j(nullptr) { j = c.j; }
};

int main() {
    Counter c1;       // Calling DMI for j.
    Counter c2 = c1;

    // Delete resource common for c1 and c2.
    delete c2.p;  // OK, no resources leaked.
}
```

you will be overriding the DMI for the data member `j`.

Note that you will need to take extra care when implementing manual memory management in terms of raw C-style pointers, which is a very common recipe for lifetime issues. If possible, instead rely on smart pointers such as `std::unique_pointer` or `std::shared_pointer` to avoid lifetime issues; this is, however, out of scope for this question. Note, also that in the contrived examples above, the copy constructor will be *shallow-copying* the `int` resource to which the `j` data member pointer of the copy-in argument points (and likely owns). For implementing a real case copy constructor, you likely want to deep-copy this resource.

Answer (score 1):

The construction instantiation `int* j = new int[5];` will trigger if there are no overwrites on it.

Let me give an example:

```
class Counter {
public:
   Counter(int x) {}; // j will be initialized as int* j = new int[5];
   Counter(double y) : j(nullptr) {}; // the line  j = new int[5]; won't be invoked. instead j = nullptr;

   int* j = new int[5];
 }
```

By default copy constructor overwrites it by copying `j`.

So if you explicitly write copy constructor like

```
Counter(const Counter& c) : j(c.j) {};
```

it will work properly. But if you write it like

```
Counter(const Counter& c) {j=c.j;};
```

it will cause a memory leak.